# Appending to a const char* array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this array:

```
const char* dllPaths[] = { "C:\\mydll.dll" };
```

and i want to append a new item to it so it will be { "C:\mydll.dll", "the thing i want to append"}

So far i tried to use a buffer to store the new array and then to delete the `dllPaths` variable from the memory and then to realocate the new array but did not worked.

Comment: is it sufficient to make it non-const?

Comment: Arrays in c++ are fix-sized, you initially declare their size. If you need a container to append to, consider using a [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or a [list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: Remember that you can only `delete` what you `new`, so using the same pointer to point to a buffer you manually allocated and to a buffer that was automatically allocated for you can get confusing fast. You need to have extra book-keeping to tell you whether or the value must be manually released, and that's usually not worth it. If you can't use a [container class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) to manage the buffer for you, do your best to keep the different types of allocations separate.

Comment: PSA: This is why `std::string` exists.

Comment: That's what I thought, then I read the question a few more times and came to the conclusion that the asker wanted an array of strings, so `vector` really is the better option. At least to start.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this, and why you can't simply edit the (source file or header) containing the definition of the array, and rebuild the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot append to arrays in C++, and you can't shrink them, in any way, either. C++ simply does not work this way. In C++ the size of all arrays is known, and fixed, at compile time, and cannot be changed. This is fundamental to C++, there are no exceptions and workarounds.

```
const char* dllPaths[] = { "C:\\mydll.dll" };
```

When the size of an array in unspecified, the C++ compiler will helpfully calculate it for you. your C++ compiler knows that this array contains only one pointer, so this is really `dllPaths[1]`, and forever it shall be so.

If you want to have an array-like object whose contents can change at runtime, then this is what `std::vector` is for, and this should be `std::vector<const char *>`, or, better yet, `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: or if you need it pre-sorted for fast searches, `std::map<std::string>`